# How to make syntax highlighting in Bash with sed and Regex?

Tags: regex, bash, syntax

I am trying to make a simple syntax highlighter in bash. I am targeting a bash script that is first copied in /tmp so I can replace every keyword with color + keyword + reset_color. I just cannot figure (nor find) a way to highlight all the strings (defined between double quotes ") in this file.

Do you have any idea on how to craft a regex (to use it with sed) that will help me replace every "*" pattern with `\e[93m"*"\e39m` where * is the content between the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you try the following:

```
sed $'s/"[^"]*"/\e[93m&\e[0m/g' file.txt
```

- The regex `"[^"]*"` matches with a substring enclosed by double quotes.
- The ampersand `&` in the replacement refers to the matched portion.

Comment: This highlighting method is very clever. Would be great if you could explain the meaning of the code segments. Can you provide a reference that describes this in more details. Thanks

Comment: @elmclose which is your main interest, regex with `sed` or text highlighting with ANSI sequence?
If you have a specific question, I'd recommend you to create a new thread referring
this discussion. Instead if you want to gather general information, I will point you to
some references according to your response. BR.